# Trying to take a screenshot to camera roll without a navigation/status bar in the image - Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, screenshot

Using: Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

My screenshot works fine, I just need to omit the navigation bar from the image in my camera roll. This is what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)        
}
```

Comment: You know the height of the navigation bar, so why not just crop it out before you save the image?

Comment: How would I crop it?

Comment: Lots of ways. See my answer here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40820337/341994

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261205/how-come-my-cropped-screenshot-becomes-uncropped-when-i-try-to-print-from-the-ca

yes, but your method is rendering errors and my method can't permanently crop it.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply cropping out the status bar before saving would seem like the ideal solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282494/how-do-i-crop-a-uiimage-in-swift) is another post with someone doing this.

Comment: [For some reason I can't print my desired screenshot. I can't print the screenshot but it becomes uncropped once I go to the print option.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261205/how-come-my-cropped-screenshot-becomes-uncropped-when-i-try-to-print-from-the-ca)